# custom carousel in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

How do i create an LWC carausel design where the text and image are shown side by side instead of the default top and bottom.[image]

what i want is to make 1 & 2 side by side not top and bottom.
link from where i took the default one:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel/example

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible via the inbuilt LWC Carousel. There are a lot of restrictions on this component. The only elements within the carousel you can use are lightning-carousel-image, which doesn't provide much flexibility.

More information on lighting-carousel-image can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel-image/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Due to the restrictions of the standard [lightning-carousel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel/example), you would have to build your own custom component to have more flexibility and customization options here.

You can find an example of a custom LWC carousel here: [Custom Slider Component](https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/customSlider)